# How to load the Docker Container logs without lines limit

Tags: logging, docker

I have a question about docker logs for container. One of my container crashed so I would like to read the logs for this container to figure out what's wrong. 
I use the command :

```
docker logs [containerId]
```

and the log shows on my terminal windows. However, the logs are too long and the terminal could not show all the logs for that container. I saw some error information in logs from the apps running on the container but it flushes so quickly and I cannot read it. I could only read some of the botton logs. Is there a way to load all the log information in the terminal without a line limit? Also I am using the windows10, where can I find out the logs for the certain container or is there anyway to save the logs files?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the buffer size of your windows terminal or you can redirect the logs to a file in the following manner :

```
docker logs container_name >> c:\\fileName.txt
```